Beautifull Soup не видит теги и атрибуты
Всем привет.
Пытаюсь спарсить цены на газобетонновые блоки с сайта https://sm.lsr.ru/spb/catalog/kirpich-gazobeton/gazobeton/kikerinskiy-gazobetonnyy-zavod/plotnost-d200/.
Получаю
[]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Интересует, вот этот кусок (itemprop="price" content="7990.00"):


    <div class="b-price " itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <div class="b-price__current "><span>7990 <sup>00</sup></span> ₽/м3</div>
                        
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="7990.00">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
                
                    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
                
    </div>



Пишу код:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        
res = requests.get('https://sm.lsr.ru/spb/catalog/kirpich-gazobeton/gazobeton/kikerinskiy-gazobetonnyy-zavod/plotnost-d200/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
soup.find_all(attrs={'itemprop' : 'offers'})

получаю
[]

или пробую так
soup.find_all('meta')

получаю:
[<meta charset="utf-8"/>,
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>,
 <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>]


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?

Либо итерируйтесь по soup.find_all(attrs={'itemprop' : 'offers'}), явно получая атрибут text и потом strip(), либо лучшее решение: soup.find({'meta': 'price'}).get('content')

Дело в том, что soup.find_all(attrs={'itemprop' : 'offers'}) отдает пустой результат [], а soup.find({'meta': 'price'}).get('content') тоже отдает пустоту

А вы пробовали напечатать, что в res.text получается? Может там через JavaScript содержимое сайта потом генерируется. Тогда вам нужен будет Selenium.

Видимо вы правы, напечатал res.text, там нет таких объектов.

Проблема в том, что вы не передаете в заголовке запроса параметр User-Agent, если не передать его, то ответом будет ошибка HTTP 403 Forbidden.
Вот исправленный вариант кода:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://sm.lsr.ru/spb/catalog/kirpich-gazobeton/gazobeton/kikerinskiy-gazobetonnyy-zavod/plotnost-d200/"
headers = {"User-Agent": "UA/Python 0.0.1"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print(soup.find_all("meta", attrs={"itemprop" : "price"}))

[<meta content="7990.00" itemprop="price"/>, <meta content="7990.00" itemprop="price"/>, <meta content="7990.00" itemprop="price"/>]


Благодарю, все работает! Вы очень помогли!

А если посмотреть на этот url = https://sm.lsr.ru/spb/catalog/kirpich-gazobeton/gazobeton/kikerinskiy-gazobetonnyy-zavod/plotnost-d600_1/bloki-iz-gazobetona-d600-100-250-625_1/
То здесь также не вижу [span] Плотность газобетона, тут какой надо headers указывать?
Возможно подскажете, где почитать какие headers в каких случая могут помочь?

он получается не видит таблицу с набором параметров div где class="b-table"

заголовки остаются прежними (User-Agent), попробуйте вытащить все элементы таблицы soup.find_all("div", class_="b-table__item").

soup.find_all("div", class_="b-table__item") отдает []
